# python simulate time and find the end of every month

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate time change in my program. For example, if I start (today) from 0 26th Oct 2016 (my var 'param' starts from 0), then one second in the real world will be one hour in my program. So every 1 second passed my 'param += 1'. Then I can simulate the time change in hours.

Now I want to do some stats in the every beginning of **every month**. in this case, the 1st stats I want to do is at 0am on the 1st of Nov 2016. My question is how can I find this point (the beginning of every month) by the value of 'param'

```
today = date.today()
    if t0 == '0':
        time_now = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
    else:
        time_now = (today + relativedelta(hours=int(param))).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

Comment: When the month value `%m` changes from its previous value, you have entered a new month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3600 seconds in an hour. Therefore, your game time is always the elapsed 'realtime' (timedelta) multiplied by 3600.

```
import datetime
def time_shift(t1, t2):
    '''returns the game-time timedelta based on two 'real' datetime objects'''
    real_elapsed = t2 - t1
    game_elapsed = real_elapsed * 3600
    return game_elapsed
```

Example:

```
>>> t1 = datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=10, day=26)
>>> delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30) 
#lets say 30 seconds realtime passes
#that should be 1 day 6 hours game-time.
>>> t2 = t1 + delta
>>> time_shift(t1, t2)
datetime.timedelta(1, 21600) #1 day, 21600 seconds IE 1 day and 6 hours
#You can translate that to a specific date for the game, too
>>> game_date = t1 + time_shift(t1, t2)
>>> game_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 27, 6, 0)
```

If you want to get the time until the first day of the next month. We can do that as follows. I'll assume we already have the current date/time in-game as `current_datetime`

```
cur_month, cur_year = current_datetime.month, current_datetime.year
try:
    next_month = datetime.datetime(year=cur_year, month=cur_month+1, day=1)
except ValueError:
    #If it was december
    next_month = datetime.datetime(year=cur_year+1, month=1, day=1)
until_next_month = next_month - current_datetime
```

Instead of a try/except you could also simply test `if cur_month != 12`

OR

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def next_month(current_datetime):
    return (current_datetime + relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)


def hours_until(dt1, dt2):
    delta = dt2 - dt1
    hours = (delta.hours * 24) + (delta.seconds / 3600)
    return hours
```

Comment: maybe my question wasn't very clear. What I really want to know is the difference between now and the very end of the month in terms of hours or days

Comment: @wildcolor Ah, I see now. Sorry about that, my mistake. I've edited my answer to include this information as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I actually had my own answer in mind already. But your answer also helps a lot. Could you actually let me know how I can change 'until_next_month' into the 'num_of_hours'?

Comment: @wildcolor In this case, `until_next_month` would be a `datetime.timedelta` object, which represents the time-delta in days/seconds/microseconds. To convert this to hours, you could do `hours = (until_next_month.days * 24) + (until_next_month.seconds / 3600)`

Comment: @wildcolor I also added a suggestion using `relativedelta` to find the appropriate date, and showing how to get the number of hours between two dates.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def seconds_until_next_month():
    return (datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=1) +
            relativedelta(months=1) - datetime.now()).seconds


def hours_until_next_month():
    return seconds_until_next_month()/60.0/60.0
```

The trick here is to use `dateutil.relativedelta` to increment the current month. This will properly wrap near the end of the year.

Comment: relativedelta is a good approach. I originally thought that February might cause a problem (IE `Jan30 + relativedelta(months=1)`) but it appropriately makes it February 29, instead of March, like I thought it might.

Comment: @sytech Yes. That is why it goes to the first of the next month, instead of adding days or whatever. That takes care of all the leap year, etc stuff.